# The bottom part of The form animates

Tags: html, css, forms

So I made this login in form for a practice but i ran into a problem when creating the button at a smaller screen it cases the entire form to animate a little and i dont know why i tried putting transition none on @media query I made for wider screen size and tried putting the transition none
on it but it did not work i even tried putting it on the container it self but it did not work.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 65.5%;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.learn {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(min-width:85rem) {
    .learn .bg-color-container {
        max-width: 40rem;
        width: 100%;





    }






    .bg-color-container button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 420px;
        padding: 2rem 0;





    }




}




    form .input__data {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .bg-color-container {
    
        background-color: rgb(236, 244, 243);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        padding: 5rem 1.8rem;
        border-radius: 1.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    
    }
    
    .dec-adder h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: -3rem;
        max-width: 250px;
        font-size: 3.1rem;
    
    }
    
    input {
        padding: 1.2rem;
        margin-top: .4rem;
    
    }
    
    [type=email],
    [type=password] {
        background: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: .5rem;
    
    
    
    }
    
    .separate-content {
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
    }
    
    .separate-content input {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
        font-weight: bolder;
    
    
    }
    
    form button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 320px;
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        transition: 2s ease-in;
        cursor: pointer;
    
        color: black;
    }
    
    form button:hover {
        background-color: #7c47c0;
    
    
    
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    form label {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<section class="learn">
        

        <div class="bg-color-container dec-adder">
            <h1>Sign in with your credentials</h1>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" autofocus required placeholder="Your Address">
                </div>
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="lg-password">Enter Passward</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Security-Passcode" id="lg-password" required>
                </div>
                <label class="separate-content" for="lg-remember">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="lg-remember" id="lg-remember" required> Remember Me
                </label>
                <div><button type="submit ">Sign Up</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>

        
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply remove `padding: 2rem 0;` from `.bg-color-container button` from under the media query.  That padding adds a height to the button and the entire form needs to shrink or grow to accommodate that padding being added or subtracted.  If you still need the padding I suggest adding a new CSS for `.bg-color-container button` outside of the media query and it will always be there.

Take a look here:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 65.5%;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.learn {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(min-width:85rem) {
    .learn .bg-color-container {
        max-width: 40rem;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .bg-color-container button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 420px;
    }

}




    form .input__data {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .bg-color-container {
    
        background-color: rgb(236, 244, 243);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        padding: 5rem 1.8rem;
        border-radius: 1.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    
    }
    
    .dec-adder h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: -3rem;
        max-width: 250px;
        font-size: 3.1rem;
    
    }
    
    input {
        padding: 1.2rem;
        margin-top: .4rem;
    
    }
    
    [type=email],
    [type=password] {
        background: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: .5rem;
    
    
    
    }
    
    .separate-content {
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
    }
    
    .separate-content input {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
        font-weight: bolder;
    
    
    }
    
    form button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 320px;
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        transition: 2s ease-in;
        cursor: pointer;
    
        color: black;
    }
    
    form button:hover {
        background-color: #7c47c0;
    
    
    
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    form label {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
   .bg-color-container button {
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }
```

```html
<section class="learn">
        

        <div class="bg-color-container dec-adder">
            <h1>Sign in with your credentials</h1>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" autofocus required placeholder="Your Address">
                </div>
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="lg-password">Enter Passward</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Security-Passcode" id="lg-password" required>
                </div>
                <label class="separate-content" for="lg-remember">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="lg-remember" id="lg-remember" required> Remember Me
                </label>
                <div><button type="submit ">Sign Up</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>

        
    </section>
```

But if you still want the button to grow in height as well without affecting the rest of the form, I'd suggest assigning the `div` containing the button a class and then give that div a fixed height.  Like this:

```css
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 65.5%;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

body {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.learn {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(min-width:85rem) {
    .learn .bg-color-container {
        max-width: 40rem;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .bg-color-container button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 420px;
        padding: 2rem 0;
    }

}




    form .input__data {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 1rem 0;
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .bg-color-container {
    
        background-color: rgb(236, 244, 243);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        padding: 5rem 1.8rem;
        border-radius: 1.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    
    }
    
    .dec-adder h1 {
        position: relative;
        top: -3rem;
        max-width: 250px;
        font-size: 3.1rem;
    
    }
    
    input {
        padding: 1.2rem;
        margin-top: .4rem;
    
    }
    
    [type=email],
    [type=password] {
        background: #ffffff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: .5rem;
    
    
    
    }
    
    .separate-content {
        position: relative;
        top: -2.1rem;
    }
    
    .separate-content input {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
        font-weight: bolder;
    
    
    }
    
    form button {
        max-width: 100%;
        width: 320px;
        padding: 1.5rem 0;
        border-radius: 1rem;
        border: none;
        background: #fff;
        transition: 2s ease-in;
        cursor: pointer;
    
        color: black;
    }
    
    form button:hover {
        background-color: #7c47c0;
    
    
    
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    form label {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    
    .btncontain {
   height: 2rem;
    }
```

```html
 <section class="learn">
        

        <div class="bg-color-container dec-adder">
            <h1>Sign in with your credentials</h1>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="Email" autofocus required placeholder="Your Address">
                </div>
                <div class="input__data">
                    <label for="lg-password">Enter Passward</label>
                    <input type="password" name="Security-Passcode" id="lg-password" required>
                </div>
                <label class="separate-content" for="lg-remember">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="lg-remember" id="lg-remember" required> Remember Me
                </label>
                <div class="btncontain"><button type="submit ">Sign Up</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>

        
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add dimensions of smaller screens in your media query (`max-width: 600px` for screens smaller than 600 pixels width) and then give them styling whatever you want. I hope this helps but you can attach your CSS if it doesn't work.

Comment: yea i did that but for a wider screen size tho

Comment: That's because you have added `transition: 2s ease-in;` in your `form button`. Remove 2s from it or if you want smooth transition change the value to `transition: 0.3s ease-in;`. This will not remove animation but make it looks good and smooth as well.

Comment: yea I know that it animates the rest starts animating

Comment: well you have changed size of button and then added transition. this will also change the size of overall container which means your whole container has to adjust its size accordingly but also that's an animation so it animates.

Comment: some other things you can do is to make your whole section of fixed width and height, say `500px` then it will not animate the whole form.

Comment: wait can show me a demo if its not too much

Comment: wait i did that but the section has to have a height set to 100vh in order for it to center in the middle of the page

Comment: i tried what you said but it stills animate the bottom part of it

Comment: and if i changed the width of the bottom then add the transition wouldnt i need to also add a fix width for when it gets at the larger screen

Comment: `.bg-color-container {
    
        background-color: rgb(236, 244, 243);
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        padding: 5rem 1.8rem;
        border-radius: 1.2rem;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 8px 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        height: 450px;
    }`

Comment: I just added `height: 450px` to your class `.bg-color-container` and it fixed all the animation thing

Comment: i see thanks for the help this helped i also say another it wish i could have solve thanks to what you have pointed out